# How would I write this from c to python?

Tags: python, c, cryptography

I need to convert this to python for my use, I have a file that I want to check for this sequence and I have this code below.
Im thinking it will be something like this but unsure how exactly

pkgrep.py

```
with open('wallet.dat') as reader:
     my_data = reader.read()
     while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == 0x81 && getchar() == 0xd3 && getchar() == 0x02 && getchar() == 0x01 &&
        getchar() == 0x01 && getchar() == 0x04 && getchar() == 0x20)){
           for(i = 0; i < 32; i ++):
               printf("%02x", getchar());
           printf("\n");
     }
```

pkgrep.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int c, i;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if (c == 0x81 &&
        getchar() == 0xd3 && getchar() == 0x02 && getchar() == 0x01 &&
        getchar() == 0x01 && getchar() == 0x04 && getchar() == 0x20) {
      for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        printf("%02x", getchar());
      printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't language tags that have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Why are you calling C functions in the Python version?

Comment: `reader.read()` reads the entire file into a string. You can then just loop over the characters of `my_data`, you don't need to keep calling `getchar()`.

Comment: My fault, I didn't mean to.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the string in `my_data`, then get the next 32 bytes with a slice.

Open the file in binary mode to ensure there's no character decoding, and search for the byte string.

```
with open('wallet.dat', 'rb') as reader:
    my_data = reader.read()
pos = my_data.find(b"\x81\xd3\x02\x01\x01\x04\x20")
if (pos != -1) {
    for x in my_data[pos+7:pos+39]:
        print(f"{x:02x}", end="")
    print()
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to use binary mode and convert the bytes to numbers.

Comment: print(f"{ord(x):02x}", end="")
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Comment: Sorry, it's indexing a byte string returns the code, I didn't need to convert it.